# How to write designMode = 'on' without js

Tags: javascript, html

Is posible to set iFrame to `designmode` without JavaScript? Or write something inside without Javascript?

```
<iframe designmode="on">

</iframe>
```

Comment: Neither manually nor JS. then what? It is only way buddy because anything which can be modified on client-side is reponsibility of JS or you can use PHP lol :P

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: for example if i want to add chat messages inside the iframe by looping them in php, but i can't do that, i use javascript to do that, but is to complicated, but i am guessing that there are a better way

Comment: so it looks like there are no way?

Comment: @Hello — How would design mode (which allows the user to type things into a document) help you add chat messages with PHP?

Comment: no, i mean the both things, adding something inside the iframe AND setting the designmode = 'on' without javascript, sorry for 2 questions, but are some of them posible to do?

Comment: @Hello — Focus on one question at a time. Why do you want design mode on at all?

Comment: because what if the javascript is disabled in the browser, then the typing in the iframe will be not possible, my chat will work with reload if there are no javascript enabled, but the iframe must work

Comment: @Hello — What benefit will typing into the iframe bring to the user? Presumably if you are implementing a chat system then you will want to send the typed in data to the server (so it can be sent to other users). How do you propose to do that if JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: i have a form and a textarea(or it can by also an iframe) and a button to send, if javascript is disabled, the user can type some message and then send it, and it will be saved in database, yes the others users will have to reload manually the page without javascript, but i want to work the iframe not depending of javascript, okay i understand there are no way :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Install a tool like Firebug or use Chrome, inspect the frame and change it's attributes. That way, you can make any change to the web page without JavaScript.

The problem is that this won't achieve much: The change will just be local in your web browser window. So if the page displays something from a remote server, then the server won't notice you messing with the HTML it sent you a while ago.

What might work is asking the company that runs the chat system whether there is an API that you can use to post messages from a computer program. A lot of web services listen to JSON or XML messages.

Comment: i don't think that users will do that(enabling design mode = on)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't change your users. I can only tell you what the technology allows. Given these options, your users can chose which they prefer.